# Having issue pushing node app to heroku node ./bin/www?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have seen a few of these around but I cant seem to get anything working. After pushing my app to heroku I get an application error. This app was created using the command in the console `$ express -e` Posted are my logs and the ./bin/www file. Thanks for any help

www file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('chore-tracker:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Logs:

```
2015-07-11T22:05:38.685748+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-07-11T22:05:38.685749+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-11T22:05:39.520258+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 48390 is already in use

2015-07-11T22:05:39.517119+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Running on port:48390
2015-07-11T22:05:39.576888+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2015-07-11T22:05:39.577550+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chore-     tracker@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.

2015-07-11T22:05:39.578012+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-07-11T22:05:39.578136+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question I have seen elsewhere, but what I found that worked was not in any answer. It would have helped possibly if I would have posted my app.js file too. What Heroku didn't like was I had 'app.listen(port);' in both my app.js file and my ./bin/www file. I commented out the one in my app.js file so only the www file was listening, and then committed the change to git, and pushed back to heroku master. Then `$ heroku open` and it worked